# How to omit empty values from PredictTimeSeries DMX query

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dmx-ssas

I'm using the `PredictTimeSeries` function within the DMX query in order to get some values predictions, as follows:

```
select flattened
 PredictTimeSeries([MiningModel_8].[Values], 100)
from 
[MiningModel_8]
```

It works well, the only problem is that at some point, the result set returns empty values, like so:

```
Expression.$TIME    Expression.Values
-------------------------------------
30/04/2015          6
01/05/2015          4
02/05/2015          4
03/05/2015          3
04/05/2015          3
05/05/2015          <<-- here it becomes empty
06/05/2015 
07/05/2015
```

How can I cut the empty rest of the result set (so the last record in the above example would be from `04/05/2015`)?

Any advice or help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can limit the result set by using WHERE clause. More details:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132048.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I already tried this one, e.g. `where [Values] = 3` but the query doesn't return anything. Although I know there are values that equals to `3`. Not sure why.